# How do I get each comma-separated tokens inside parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I achieve the following result using regular expressions?

```
"(apple, banana, _orange)" # => ['apple', 'banana', '_orange']
"apple, banana, _orange"   # => []
"(apple)"                  # => ['apple']
"()"                       # => []
"(apple,sauce)"            # => ['apple', 'sauce']
```

This is what I have so far but I am only able to capture the last token:

```
\|(?:(?:,\s)?(\w+))*\|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
/\b\w+\b(?=.*\))/m
```

[it works for all your provided sample](http://ideone.com/CGCPrg):

```
re = /\b\w+\b(?=.*\))/m
str1 = '(apple, banana, _orange)'
str2 = 'apple, banana, _orange'
str3 = '(apple)'
str4 = '()'
str5 = '(apple,sauce)'

p str1.scan(re)
p str2.scan(re)
p str3.scan(re)
p str4.scan(re)
p str5.scan(re)
```

Sample Output:

```
["apple", "banana", "_orange"]
[]
["apple"]
[]
["apple", "sauce"]
```

But ideally this is not the best solution as it doesn't check whether it starts with a ( or not. 
If you really have to use regex then you can not do it perfectly with one regex:

1. You will first need to check if the string starts and ends with
   partenthesis
2. then you need to scan the string by the second regex \b\w+\b

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex :

```
/(?<=\().*?(?=\))/
```

to scan for text between parens, and then split it around `','`.

```
strings = [
  '(apple, banana, _orange)', 
  'apple, banana, _orange', 
  '(apple)', 
  '()', 
  '(apple,sauce)',
  '(apple) orange (sauce)',
  'not properly closed)'
]

strings.each do |string|
  p string.scan(/(?<=\().*?(?=\))/).flat_map { |s| s.split(',') }
end

# =>
# ["apple", " banana", " _orange"]
# []
# ["apple"]
# []
# ["apple", "sauce"]
# ["apple", "sauce"]
# []
```

It requires 2 steps, but it should be more resilient than just a single regex.